# How would I encrypt something like this;

Tags: encryption

I want to encrypt some very important passwords in a text document or something like it. What would I use to ensure maximum security.

Comment: Related: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17135/notes-behind-password-tool

Comment: "Maximum Security" is too broad of a term. There are many "sufficient" encryption algorithms you could use, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try a password manager such as [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) or [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/).

The passwords will be stored securely using a master password and other criteria you may designate to encrypt them so you can ensure that your passwords are safe. They also offer other functionality as well.

Keepass for instance has an auto-fill feature which will make an attempt to enter your password into the form securely. There are also password generators included to allow you to make incredibly complex passwords and not have to commit them to your brain's memory.

This is preferential to a text document as you'll be protecting your sensitive data using several layers of security. It's also much easier to stay organized with the managers as well, if you use their categories properly.

Comment: I would like to put the encypted text and the key on 2 USBs

Comment: I would recommend storing the master key in your head, using a passphrase of at least 5 words (ex. "Marget Thatcher is 110% sexy!") to prevent the key being stolen along with your password db. You could copy the password database over to each USB although I think it'd be a bit of a hassle updating two usbs. Can I ask what the reasoning is for using two usbs over just one?

Comment: Okay I will do one USB, I was just going to put the key in one and the passwords (encrypted) in the other one... Do you know a program where I can encrypt my passwords than move it over to a USB?

Comment: With Keepass, for instance, you can store the password DB it creates on your USB. The program itself does the encryption based on your master password (Something you know), and if you choose to, a key file that is generated by the program (something you have). You would need to have KeePass installed on the computer you wish to retrieve passwords from, however.

Comment: Do you know something that I don't need to download something to read it.

Comment: I suppose you could keep KeePass' executable on the USB as well, if connectivity is an issue.